# Allow ELB connection just from instances in the same VPC, Subnet and Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-security-group

I am working fine with my current ELB, but for security reasons i want to restrict connections by allowing just instances in the same security group, so i created an aditional security group just for mange only the ELB, i have no problem while i allow 0.0.0.0/0 to the 443 port, but when i remove the rule i am losing the connection, if i allow the public ip of the instance it will work, but i have several instances so it is not an option, i also tried allowing private CIDR (10.0.0.0/24) of the instances and it does not work, and i also tried allowing same security groups with not success

[image: ELB Security Group]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need more info but it looks like you're hitting your ELB from a public IP address.

Comment: wget on the ELB url?  If you're ELB is public your traffic will be routed out your internet gateway either using a public IP if you're using a public subnet or a NAT IP if you're using a private subnet.

Comment: @kenlukas I am doing WGET from an instance in the same VPC and security group, but the instance is not part of the Target Group for the ELB

Comment: @kenlukas WGET from instance to a domain that points to ELB url, when i add a rule allowing the public ip of the instance; it works well, but i have several instances so i cannot add one by one manualy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup should be:

- A **security group on the Amazon EC2 instances** running your app (`SG-App`) that permits incoming traffic from the appropriate locations to access the app
- A **security group on the Load Balancer** (`SG-LB`) that permits inbound connections on port 443 from `SG-App`

That is, `SG-App` is permitting inbound connections from any instances associated with `SG-App`. This is much better than allowing connections "from the same security group" because the instances need different settings to the ELB.

When the instances resolve the DNS Name associated with the Load Balancer, it should resolve to a **private IP address** (`10.0`). You can test this by connecting to one of the instances and trying to ping/lookup the ELB DNS Name and seeing what IP address it is using.

Comment: I am doing right that, in the image you would see sg-b6f2c3c8 that is the SG-App but the DNS resolves to ELB public IP, it is not resolving to private IP

Comment: Ah! When creating an ELB, there is a **Scheme** option offering two choices: "An Internet-facing load balancer routes requests from clients over the Internet to targets. An internal load balancer routes requests from clients to targets using private IP addresses." I suspect you would need to re-create the ELB and select `internal` to have it resolve to a private IP address.

Comment: It sound good, but i spread an url with https://elb.mydomain.com in my app that is pointing to ELB through Route 53 with A Alias record, so it would be too much work to change the url in whole app code, and the app is runing in 443 port so it is needed https

Comment: You would need to launch a new "internal" ELB and connect it to the same target groups (which mean that both ELBs work the same). Then you can edit the Route 53 entry to point to the new ELB. Over a period of time, traffic will move to the new ELB. Then you can delete the old ELB. It will also be cheaper because traffic that goes from a VPC to a public IP address is charged at 1c/GB, even if it goes back into the same VPC. ("Data transferred “in” to and “out” from public or Elastic IPv4 address is charged at $0.01/GB in each direction.")